# Reapplying to Ph.D. Programs: Ways to improve?

Tags: phd, application

This year, I applied to Ph.D. programs in history, hoping to continue my research. Unfortunately, I discovered that, despite a "strong application," I was not admitted to any of the programs to which I applied. While I was told that it was not because of my application, but rather a school's lack of focus on my particular field of study, I cannot help but think about how a gap year will look when I re-apply next year.

In the gap, I intend to teach in a high school (and potentially community college), but I am unsure of what I can do to improve my application for future applications. A year-long gap is frustrating, personally. **I would appreciate any advice on what I can do to increase my chances. How might the gap year look to programs? What, exactly, would help me improve/enhance my application? Thank you, in advance.**

**Brief Outline of Background:**

B.A. in history, magna cum laude with distinction (Honors Thesis), Conferred 2016

M.A.T in History Education, awarded Hattie M. Strong Fellowship for teaching excellence, Conferred 2017

MA in East Asian Studies, awarded two travel grants for conference presentations, Expected May 2020

I have continually presented in academic conferences since my sophomore year as an undergraduate  and am currently working on a book review article and journal article for publication

I maintain a strong GPA from all institutions attended, despite working a full-time job, serving as a Graduate TA, and taking a full courseload (sometimes more).

I have strong references from well-known scholars in the field, all of whom I keep in constant contact.

The only area I could see a need to improve is my language acquisition. While I know Japanese, I would like to add Chinese (and perhaps Korean) to my list of languages. This is currently in progress.

While this is by no means an exhaustive list, and it is difficult to judge without all the available facts, I would appreciate your insights.

Comment: *"While I was told that it was not because of my application, but rather a school's lack of focus on my particular field of study"* - and what is that particular field of study? Is it something likely to be controversial or very niche?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think your suggestions aren't likely to help much. You are suggesting making your CV more diverse while doctoral research requires more focus/specialization. You've already been told what is lacking, and you have a lot of breadth already in your CV.

Either find a program that matches what you want to do, as the places you've already applied to do not, or match your short term goals to some program(s) that do exist and are taking students. I think the latter is probably more viable.

Write a SoP with the knowledge of what is supported by the places you apply to. If they have no way to move outside their range of expertise they have little incentive to accept you, no matter how good you are.

But it is only a short term twisting of the path to success. A doctoral program in a field somewhat related to your long term goals will give you both the skills and the credential to research in the future as you like. The specific topic of your dissertation need not be limiting.

But you've got to get in the door first. And specialization is the name of the game played in that space.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I also think that the latter option you suggest is the most probable. I don't necessarily want to make my CV more diverse, in fact, it's just the opposite. For future applications, I intend to discuss my specific, specialized interest within a larger context (which ties into my second interest). For example, my research in Japanese history and memory fits well with my interest in Japanese history in a global context. Thank you for your advice, I appreciate it.